# Tools and notation to design sofware in Go

Tags: go

UML is used to design Object-oriented software, but programs that are going to be developmed in Go are not 100% Object-oriented. What tools and notation are used to design software in Go? E.g. what is the equivalent to  class diagrams, maybe a struct diagram or sequence diagram? What tools could I use to create such diagrams?

Comment: @OneOfOne then how represent a module which is so big. e.g. there are 5 developers and they are doing a module. how I know that they develoment that the company want and not they want or imagine.  

Another case is how to give documentation to a custumer when a project is ended. the program in Go could not be a black box.

Comment: Check Godoc, you don';t need to write separate documentation at all, also as a developer for almost 15 years, you want the end product to act the way you want, let the developers do it anyway they want.

Comment: For a detailed treatment of converting UML to CSP (Hoare's Communicating Sequential Processes) have a look at http://www.informatik.uni-marburg.de/~swt/agtive-contest/UML-to-CSP.pdf and http://rcos.iist.unu.edu/qvttoxslt/ActivityToCSP-example.htm . Not sure about tooling, but they should point you in the right direction.

Comment: "What tools and notation are used to design software in Go?" Human brain and natural language? And of course UML: There's much more (and IMHO more useful) stuff in UML than class diagrams.

Comment: UML has classes (which you can use for Go structs) components (Go packages) and interfaces, so there is no reason you can't use UML to model Go code.... C++ can also have procedural code like Go, and yet people use UML to model it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

UML is far from being restricted to OO languages, even the most "OO diagram", class diagram. UML defines syntactic rules, but the semantic interpretation is very extensible using stereotypes mechanism (and other elements, e.g. tagged values).

You can even use class diagrams, eventually first creating a UML profile for Go.